# Mount If Available

Tags: networking, mount, automounting

I have access to a few network hosted drives with different types of protocols (smb, webdav icsi, NFS probably more webdav and smb but I want include maybe more). Those drives are not always accessible (at home only over VPN directly at work).

My plan is the following:

- I have a list with `type`, `server`, `path`
- foreach line I ping the `$server` single time low responsetime
- if ping success and `$path` not mounted -> mount drive depending on `$type` (local directory checking included)
- if ping fail and `$path` mounted -> try umount

I am not sure what happens if umount fails because a file is still open, but I already have the scenario if I leave the network and mounted a webdav drive manually, but this is something I want to handle as future me.

Technically I am able to create a bash script based on the pseudo code about. At the end I want to package (aur) the script and a template list together with a systemd.unit and a systemd.timer.

My question now exists a package already which achieves the above or similar and if not I am unsure about the intervals for the timer unit. Should I tend to every 10 seconds? or should I keep the timeouts of the different protocols in mind?

I have read a bit about AutoFS but I am not sure if this will satisfy my situation.

Comment: Both autofs and systemd can do automount nowadays. Please don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: systemd automount sounds better fitting my purpose than autofs. But two things are bothering me: What happens if the drive is not accessible? If I have multiple drives I want to mount with systemd do I have to create for all drives a seperate mount unit?

Comment: I think there is a documentation…

Comment: Yes thats right and I already digged into it. As far as I understand to utelize multiple drives and don't create all the units manually, FSTAB is capable of creating automount units.  This is something I didn't expected but good to know.